# Application error ao efetuar heroku open

Tags: node.js, heroku

Boas pessoal, comecei há uns dias atrás a utilizar a `Mean Stack` e ainda estou muito no inicio. Estou usando o livro *Getting Mean with MongoDb, express, angular and node.js* . Estou gostando bastante do livro, mas devido ao avanço das tecnologias não sei se estou seguindo o caminho correto, quando rodo a minha aplicação no servidor local utilizando o comando `heroku local`, a app funciona perfeitamente, mas sempre que tento fazer `heroku` open para verificar a app no `url` live não funciona e aparece este erro:

> **Application Erro**r An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
>   If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

here is the log that i get:

```
2016-09-02T17:31:29.466147+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed 

to st
arting
2016-09-02T17:31:31.060235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2016-09-02T17:31:32.472247+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.472260+00:00 app[web.1]: > loc8r@0.0.0 start /app
2016-09-02T17:31:32.472261+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2016-09-02T17:31:32.472261+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656959+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656962+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656962+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656963+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656964+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../contr
ollers/main'
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656965+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:325:15)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656965+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:276:25)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656966+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656967+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:
12:17)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656967+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app
_server/routes/index.js:3:16)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656968+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
09:26)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656969+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:416:10)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656969+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:3
2)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656973+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:300:12)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.656977+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-09-02T17:31:32.663246+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.669346+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-93-generic
2016-09-02T17:31:32.669649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bi
n/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-09-02T17:31:32.669820+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.5.0
2016-09-02T17:31:32.670144+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.10
2016-09-02T17:31:32.670379+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-09-02T17:31:32.670497+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! loc8r@0.0.0 start: `node .
/bin/www`
2016-09-02T17:31:32.670605+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-09-02T17:31:32.670727+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-09-02T17:31:32.670835+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the loc8r@0.0.0
start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2016-09-02T17:31:32.670952+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the loc8r package,
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671058+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671161+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671268+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671371+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on
 how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671476+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs loc8r
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671578+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available
, you can get their info via:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671680+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671783+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls loc8r
2016-09-02T17:31:32.671888+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2016-09-02T17:31:32.674947+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.675113+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the followi
ng file with any support request:
2016-09-02T17:31:32.675211+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-09-02T17:31:32.730289+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-02T17:31:32.756592+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-02T18:26:28.642344+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=a4
ce8451-05ce-4dc3-abcf-2df7000c3230 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:42:34.672434+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=01
83cfff-4885-4923-aaa6-31c61ecc4cc4 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:42:35.285869+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=e8ed1870-7cbc-4670-bf0a-27462d53ba3c fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:47:12.707700+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=8c
8150a5-016a-4e42-a075-418be09c463f fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:47:13.332738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=d3887ea1-8666-4995-89b0-ff68af421326 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:47:58.629507+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=bb
3a5f50-c3ea-44f9-a47b-a6496f871380 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:47:58.819246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=5d46c193-fe59-4b95-9651-f2c0cd7ed9e4 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:56:06.121970+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=9c
19efab-13ff-4410-888f-71e2d7b5742e fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T18:56:06.344713+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=e24c914d-78c6-4b43-b2aa-c2320b70ddf7 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T19:20:45.000939+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=59
55ba8e-6065-4ff0-b23a-18cc2174ddc2 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T19:20:45.197532+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=b9b68df1-6fd4-4dbf-a302-fdd10b486dc1 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=

C:\Users\Filipe\Dropbox\Projetos Pessoais\Starting Mean Stack\loc8r>heroku confi
g:set SBT_CLEAN=true -a shrouded-garden-88708
Setting SBT_CLEAN and restarting shrouded-garden-88708... done, v5
SBT_CLEAN: true

C:\Users\Filipe\Dropbox\Projetos Pessoais\Starting Mean Stack\loc8r>heroku open

C:\Users\Filipe\Dropbox\Projetos Pessoais\Starting Mean Stack\loc8r>heroku confi
g:unset SBT_CLEAN
Unsetting SBT_CLEAN and restarting shrouded-garden-88708... done, v6

C:\Users\Filipe\Dropbox\Projetos Pessoais\Starting Mean Stack\loc8r>heroku open

C:\Users\Filipe\Dropbox\Projetos Pessoais\Starting Mean Stack\loc8r>heroku open

C:\Users\Filipe\Dropbox\Projetos Pessoais\Starting Mean Stack\loc8r>heroku logs
2016-09-02T19:24:39.385937+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-02T19:24:39.386864+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-09-02T19:24:41.075298+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2016-09-02T19:24:43.696933+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.696974+00:00 app[web.1]: > loc8r@0.0.0 start /app
2016-09-02T19:24:43.696975+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2016-09-02T19:24:43.696976+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946533+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946537+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946537+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946538+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946539+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../contr
ollers/main'
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946541+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946541+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:276:25)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946540+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:325:15)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946542+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:
12:17)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946543+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app
_server/routes/index.js:3:16)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946543+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
09:26)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946544+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:416:10)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946544+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:3
2)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:300:12)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.946545+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-09-02T19:24:43.957578+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.965386+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-09-02T19:24:43.965948+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bi
n/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-09-02T19:24:43.966199+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.5.0
2016-09-02T19:24:43.966617+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.10
2016-09-02T19:24:43.967148+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-09-02T19:24:43.967378+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! loc8r@0.0.0 start: `node .
/bin/www`
2016-09-02T19:24:43.967543+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-09-02T19:24:43.967723+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-09-02T19:24:43.967902+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the loc8r@0.0.0
start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2016-09-02T19:24:43.968269+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the loc8r package,
2016-09-02T19:24:43.968434+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-09-02T19:24:43.968594+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.968922+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on
 how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.968759+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2016-09-02T19:24:43.969115+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs loc8r
2016-09-02T19:24:43.969330+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available
, you can get their info via:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.969566+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-09-02T19:24:43.969742+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls loc8r
2016-09-02T19:24:43.969926+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2016-09-02T19:24:43.974664+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.974854+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the followi
ng file with any support request:
2016-09-02T19:24:43.974987+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-09-02T19:24:44.065799+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-02T19:24:44.052428+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-02T19:24:52.940025+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=eb
302439-b1e6-4aee-93cb-ea5aef18a562 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T19:24:53.113746+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=c6f7af47-7f96-431f-8aaf-9f7144a8443d fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T19:26:08.381201+00:00 heroku[api]: Remove SBT_CLEAN config vars by fi
lipecosta_10@hotmail.com
2016-09-02T19:26:08.381347+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by filipecosta_
10@hotmail.com
2016-09-02T19:26:08.810606+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2016-09-02T19:26:11.464159+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `n
pm start`
2016-09-02T19:26:14.482733+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.482752+00:00 app[web.1]: > loc8r@0.0.0 start /app
2016-09-02T19:26:14.482753+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2016-09-02T19:26:14.482754+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869049+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:327
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869061+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869061+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869062+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869064+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../contr
ollers/main'
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869066+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:276:25)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869067+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869067+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:
12:17)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869066+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFile
name (module.js:325:15)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869069+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/app
_server/routes/index.js:3:16)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:4
09:26)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869070+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..j
s (module.js:416:10)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869071+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (modul
e.js:300:12)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869071+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:343:3
2)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.869072+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:35
3:17)
2016-09-02T19:26:14.893057+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.902399+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-09-02T19:26:14.902856+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! argv "/app/.heroku/node/bi
n/node" "/app/.heroku/node/bin/npm" "start"
2016-09-02T19:26:14.903138+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.5.0
2016-09-02T19:26:14.904418+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2016-09-02T19:26:14.903628+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.10
2016-09-02T19:26:14.904614+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! loc8r@0.0.0 start: `node .
/bin/www`
2016-09-02T19:26:14.904799+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-09-02T19:26:14.905020+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-09-02T19:26:14.905209+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the loc8r@0.0.0
start script 'node ./bin/www'.
2016-09-02T19:26:14.905602+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-09-02T19:26:14.905775+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this
fails on your system:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.905424+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is most likely a prob
lem with the loc8r package,
2016-09-02T19:26:14.905955+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node ./bin/www
2016-09-02T19:26:14.906337+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get information on
 how to open an issue for this project with:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.906521+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm bugs loc8r
2016-09-02T19:26:14.906691+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available
, you can get their info via:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.906865+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2016-09-02T19:26:14.907032+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls loc8r
2016-09-02T19:26:14.911785+00:00 app[web.1]:
2016-09-02T19:26:14.907209+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional
 logging output above.
2016-09-02T19:26:14.912262+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-09-02T19:26:14.912122+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the followi
ng file with any support request:
2016-09-02T19:26:15.002185+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2016-09-02T19:26:15.010807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2016-09-02T19:26:18.824673+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=1e
5db958-d192-44e0-aee5-390b5ccf8a5f fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T19:26:19.012697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=f374982a-19dc-4385-ba4d-107756ceb2bc fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T19:33:53.163740+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com request_id=ba
6d6568-4634-481d-b969-51d28450d339 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect= service= st
atus=503 bytes=
2016-09-02T19:33:53.347539+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shrouded-garden-88708.herokuapp.com re
quest_id=64fad7b4-2ace-4010-942e-951901f0dbf5 fwd="89.152.47.50" dyno= connect=
service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Esse erro não te aparece se estiveres a correr localmente?

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a versão do node e do NPM no package.json

****** ERRO
***** npm ERR! node v4.5.0
****** npm ERR! npm  v2.15.10
****** ERRO

EXEMPLO: package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "4.5.0",
    "npm": "2.15.10"
  },
```